# INSERT query type is not supported yet. You can use:SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE

Tags: android-room

```
I am getting this compile error when I try this query.
```

> INSERT query type is not supported yet. You can use:SELECT, DELETE,
>   UPDATE

```
@Query("INSERT INTO table SELECT name, etc from temp_table;") 
void insertIntoTable();
```

Is there any other way to do a batch insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it using RawQuery:

```
public void addRecordsFromTempTable() {
    mDatabase.rawDao().insertRecords(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("INSERT INTO my_table (name, etc) SELECT name, et from temp_table;"));
}
```

Raw query file:

```
@Dao
public interface RawDao {
    @RawQuery()
    boolean insertRecords(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```